How can I improve target visibility and prioritization in SmokePing?
I’m using SmokePing for network monitoring but facing two key issues. I have 104 targets, and it’s difficult to visualize and identify problematic nodes due to limitations in both the sorter panels and the general overview.
In the sorter panels, data is aggregated to give an overall network view, but specific targets with issues aren’t named. Clicking a panel only shows one problematic target, usually the worst, so multiple targets with significant issues (e.g., 100% or 95% packet loss) are missed unless searched manually.
In the general overview, even with 400x50 panels on a high-res monitor, not all targets fit on the screen. Latency lines (e.g., 4 ms) are shown, but packet loss isn’t, forcing me to click each target to see detailed panels where severe packet loss often appears. This manual process is impractical with so many targets.
Is there a way to improve visibility in the sorter panels to show all affected targets in categories like packet loss, and in the general overview, can targets be sorted or prioritized by packet loss or latency issues? This would help surface critical problems without clicking each target individually.
Any advice on whether these features exist or if there are workarounds would be appreciated.
Thank you for your help!
